# How to ignore parent overflow for multiple select?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I need to make single-looking multiple select. Now I'm using bootstrap multiselect plugin, but can't make it ignore it's parent overflow: auto;

```
.pad12 {
  padding: 0 12px;
  overflow-x: auto
}
```

Here is example for better understanding click on timezone selector.
https://jsfiddle.net/Shoup/rytcoxzu/3/

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: I think my question is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add `maxHeight`

```
$('.f-timezone').multiselect({
      numberDisplayed: 1,
      maxHeight: 150,
      onChange: function (e, c) {
            e.checked = c;
        }
});
```

Add class on change event & change your CSS like `.multi .pad12`

```
    $('.f-timezone').multiselect({

    numberDisplayed: 1,
    onChange: function (e, c) {
        e.checked = c;
    },

    onDropdownShown: function (event) {
        $('body').addClass('multi')
    },
    onDropdownHidden: function (event) {
        $('body').removeClass('multi')
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/5fkythr0/1/

Comment: I'm actualy need dropdown to drop under `.pad12` but don't be affected by it's overflow.  Because selectors like f-timezone can also be lower.